# RSpec: uninitialized constant RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup::ActionController (NameError)

Tags: rspec, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm writing some tests for this [gem's](https://github.com/toadkicker/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/spec_install_generator) generator methods and getting this error. I'm wondering what I'm missing in the config to test this properly. It seems to be related to loading the rails config in this method:

```
def use_coffeescript?
  ::Rails.configuration.app_generators.rails[:javascript_engine] == :coffee
end
```

For sake of brevity, [here is the diff](https://github.com/toadkicker/twitter-bootstrap-rails/compare/spec_install_generator). Thanks in advance for any advice/links/etc!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add this to your spec_helper:

```
require 'action_controller'
```